# Cómo crear un Array bidimensional que se ajuste al contenido

Tags: java

Tengo un array de char de 3x3 que necesito empequeñecer en función del contenido. Es decir: si una de esas filas o columnas no tiene valores dentro de ellas, necesito removerla y crear un array mas pequeño.
El objetivo es que el algoritmo sea lo más compacto posible.

No necesito remover la central si X0 y X2 están llenas. En resumen, solo debería remover los bordes si estos están vacíos (X0-X2 y Y0 Y2)
Pero en caso de que X0 y X1 estén vacíos debo remover esos dos y dejar X2 solamente.

He intentado solventar mi problema con el siguiente código:

```java
                boolean y0lleno = false;
                boolean y1lleno = false;
                boolean y2lleno = false;
                boolean x0lleno = false;
                boolean x1lleno = false;
                boolean x2lleno = false;

                for (int x = 0; x < pattern.length; x++) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < pattern[x].length; y++) {
                        if (x == 0 && pattern[x][y] != ' ') {
                            x0lleno = true;
                            switch (y) {
                                case 0:
                                    y0lleno = true;
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    y1lleno = true;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    y2lleno = true;
                                    break;

                            }

                        }
                        if (x == 1 && pattern[x][y] != ' ') {
                            x1lleno = true;
                            switch (y) {
                                case 0:
                                    y0lleno = true;
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    y1lleno = true;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    y2lleno = true;
                                    break;

                            }
                        }
                        if (x == 2 && pattern[x][y] != ' ') {
                            x2lleno = true;
                            switch (y) {
                                case 0:
                                    y0lleno = true;
                                    break;
                                case 1:
                                    y1lleno = true;
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    y2lleno = true;
                                    break;

                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
```

¿Cómo debería controlar las diferentes posibilidades de la forma más óptima posible?

[image: Imagen de lo que se debería eliminar]
En la imagen he ilustrado un poco mejor a lo que me refiero. Los colores son las posibles filas que se pueden eliminar.
Podría, por ejemplo, eliminar las dos columnas rojas si están vacías (AMBAS) o las dos verdes, estén vacías las dos o solo una.

Lo mismo se aplicaría en el eje Y

Answer (score 0):

tu pregunta esta un poco complicada de entender, espero haberla comprendido bien, necesitas un programa que haga lo siguiente:
1. Recorrer un Array (Llamemosle Array 1).
2. Si el Array1 tiene espacios vacíos mover este contenido a otro Array (Array2) que tendrá como medida máxima la cantidad en espacios utilizados en el Array1.

Con ArrayList considero mas sencilla esta problemática, ya que permite manejar un arreglo de forma mas dinamica, te muestro:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Creamos los objetos Arraylist
    ArrayList array1 = new ArrayList();

    // en el array1 ocuparemos 5 espacios
    array1.add("1");
    array1.add("2");
    array1.add("3");
    array1.add("4");
    array1.add("5");

    // Mostramos el contenido del array1
    System.out.println(array1);

    // borramos el 1 y 5 de nuestro array. 
    array1.remove("1");
    array1.remove("5");

    // Mostramos el contenido del array2
    System.out.println(array1);

    // Mostramos cuanto mide nuestro array1 actualmente
    System.out.println(array1.size());
}
```

A si mismo, si en tu caso no te sirve el ArrayList puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {

    // Array 1 con 5 espacios
    // Array 2 con X espacios

    // Creamos Array con 5 espacios
    int [] array1 = new int[5];

    // Le damos valor a cada espacio del array
    array1[0] = 0;
    array1[1] = 1;
    array1[2] = 2;
    array1[3] = 3;
    array1[4] = 4;

    // Mostramos el array creado
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Posicion "+i + ": " +array1[i]);
    }


    // Saber el tamaño del array
    System.out.println("El tamaño del array1 es: " + array1.length);

    // Creamos el array2 el cual tendra como punto maximo la cantidad de valores del arreglo 1
    int [] array2 = new int[array1.length];

    // Mostrar el tamano del array
    System.out.println("El tamaño del array2 es: "+array2.length);

    //Ingresamos valores al array2
    array2[0] = 5;
    array2[1] = 4;
    array2[2] = 3;
    array2[3] = 2;
    array2[4] = 1;

    // Ver contenido del array2
    for (int i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Posicion "+i + ": " +array2[i]);
    }

}
```

Espero haber resuelto tu duda o por lo menos darte una idea de usar Arrays de forma mas dinámica, saludos!.

[image: Salida en consola del ejemplo 2]